# Displaying Hjighest and Lowest number in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying it this way. seems to be more simplified. just trying to figure out now how to include the month names and to get the program to output the name of the rainiest month not the number the user inputs.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int a[12];

    int x;
    for (x=0; x<12; x++)
    {
        cout << "Insert days of rainfall for month "<<x+1<<endl;
        cin >>a[x];
    }
    int max;
    int min;
    max = a[0];
    min = a[0];
    int e=0;
    while (e<12)
    {
        if (a[e]>max)
        {
             max = a[e];
        }
        else if (a[e]<min)
        {
            min = a[e];
        }
        e++;
        cout<<"The rainiest month was " <<max<<endl;
        cout<<"The least rainy month was " <<min<<endl;
        getch ();
        return 0;
    }


    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I dont see your attempt to solve it; you just took input; but you should write code to find the biggest/smallest number; If there is a problem only _then_ you should post your question describing your expected output and the output you got.

Comment: It would seem to me you're working awfully hard at this, Perhaps something like: `total += val;`, and `if (lowest > val) { lowest = val; lowest_month = month;}`, etc... would find a nice home in this. And a loop over a static array of months names would probably shorten this by an order of magnitude.

Comment: I'm not going to post the answer code, but here's a hint: loop and maybe an array!

Comment: @yzt Who needs loops or arrays if it's "due soon"?

Comment: `jan + feb + march + april + may + june + july + aug + sept + oct + nov+ dec/12` this does not do what you seem to think it does, due to operator precedence.  Not part of your question, but still.  `/` has a higher precedence than `+`, use `()` to group all the additions before doing the division.

Comment: some advice, rely more on the STL and replace all your variable by a sorted container in which you can add the user input, use accumulate for summing, and just first and last to get the min and max as your data will be store sorted!

Comment: I love how people who are trying to program have absolutely no idea about elementary school maths... >.<

Comment: @H2CO3: Dude, as you said, the guy doesn't know counting and elementary arithmetic. I think it's safe to say that the sarcasm will go right over his head too.

Comment: @yzt Aww... you must be right!

Answer (score 1):

Your `average` calculation is off a little, you have to take into consideration the order of operations when it comes to math.  Multiplication and division are always done first, then addition and subtraction.  What you end up with is that ONLY `dec` is divided by 12, and THEN you add all the other days to it.  To fix this, you need to wrap the additions of all of the months in parentheses to force the addition to happen first, then do the divide after.  In this case, you can just use your `year` variable since it is already all of the months added together and divide it by 12.

As far as your question goes, you want to show the highest and lowest values input, but I don't see any attempt to solve this in your code.  I feel less inclined to just write the code for you so I will just give a brief explanation of what you need to do instead.  Look at the value for each month, each time you look at the next month, you compare it with the current highest and current lowest values you remember.  When the new month has a new higher, or new lower, value you replace the value you remember.  Once you cycle through every month you will end up with your highest and lowest values.

Comment: Thanks for catching the average problem. i was wondering about that as well. as for my question, i get what u mean but i am not sure though how to write it. do i use an if/else or whatever? does it have to go between each cout<< month question?

Comment: It could go either way, personally though, I wouldn't store each month in a separate variable name, instead I would store all months in an array `month[12]`.  Then it will be easier to just loop through every month instead of writing separate lines for each one.

Comment: how would i turn my double into an array. If there is a link that you know of on this it would be greatly appreciated thanks

Comment: You just define your value like this `double months[12];`  And to access any item you start at index 0 up to 11 (or use 1-12 but subtract one from each) and access them like this `jan = months[0]; feb = months[1]; dec = months[11];`  You can easily loop through the indexes 0-11 with just a few lines.

Comment: int a[12];
    int x;
    double year,
           average'
           months[12];
    for (x=0; x<12; x++)
//Where would the index go and the actual months ex. jan = months[0]

Comment: well, the idea is that you don't use actual month variables like `jan`, instead you just use `months[0]` when you want january.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest and the most clean way is to use a container such as an `std::vector`. Then sort it using `std::sort`.

```
// Our container
std::vector<double> userInput;

// Populate the vector. Please don't cin into a double!

// Sort it.
std::sort (userInput.begin(), userInput.end());

// The highest value will be the last value in the vector
// whilst the lowest value will be the first one
```

Comment: in my textbook the exercise tells me to use an array of doubles. how can i do that but then still not cin into a double?

Comment: @user2686985 `cin >> someDouble` is bad practice, What if someone types `1.005abc` ?

Comment: @user2686985 Use `strtod` to convert cin input to double. You need to implement a check to make sure the input is actually a double!